# DVD drive becomes hidden device

Tags: windows-8, optical-drive

I have a laptop `Lenovo G580` with `Windows 8.1`, In early days when I bought this it was working normally but now a days its `DVD Drive` becomes invisible. When I go to `Control Panel> Device Manager> View> Show hidden devices` I see `DVD Drive` there in `hidden devices`. When I double click on that then the following `Dialog` appears:

[image: DVD Promlem]

I have searched out some `Discussions` on this topic [dvd-drive-disappears](https://superuser.com/questions/33962/dvd-drive-disappears) and [cd-drive-not-discovered](https://superuser.com/questions/471322/cd-drive-not-discovered), but found no any suitable solution in this case. Please suggest me a solution for this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Lenovo PCs and know this issue....

Issue: Optical disc drive is invisible in 'My Computer'

Solution:

1. WIN+R than type "REGEDIT"
2. Than find a "key"
   {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\ {than a key appears}
3. For your own security take a copy of that.
4. rightclick on it
5. Export than note somewhere
6. Delete all termins below

   1. UpperFilters
   2. LowerFilters
   3. UpperFilters.bak
   4. LowerFilters.bak
7. Than close REGEDIT
8. RESTART your PC

Optical DD is supposed to be visible and work now...
Let's delete the copy we made on the beginning.